# How to reactively monitor if Vue JS data object has changed?

Tags: vue.js

In a Vue JS project, i have the following pretty standard pattern:

```
data () {
  model: {
    id: uid(),
    label: null,
    options: []
    .... etc.
  }
}
```

The `model` property feeds a form and I need to show an alert when the data model is 'dirty' - any key may have been changed by the user since last saving.

The problem is - the data may be affected many different methods - v-model for inputs, custom events from child components like selects and toggle switches etc and the options array maybe edited by drag-and-drop sorting, adding/removing elements, etc.

I'm looking for - ideally - a single REACTIVE (eg computed) property I can watch to know if the model is dirty so I can prompt the user to save.

Does Vue have a hidden or undocumented property/method, something like $vm._isDirty? I know I can use a compare fn to handle it manually, but it's not reactive, and I know I could use a deep watcher on the model, but that's computationally expensive and some of these models are pretty big.

What approach have other developers have used?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a deep watcher:

```js
watch:
{
  model:
  {
    deep: true,
    handler(newValue, oldValue)
    {
      this.modified = true; // or whatever you need to do when the model becomes dirty
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, using deep watchers is computationally expensive and not recommended, especially for large data objects, which mine are. per Linus Borg, core team member: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/performance-cost-of-watchers-vs-emit/49626/3

Comment: Yes, deep watchers are expensive. If your objects are large - it will be better if you do not modify them directly, but use a dedicated method for each type of modification. Each of these methods will be responsible for raising the `dirty` flag - which can then be watched by a cheap watcher.